Formula to increase its month by one as it autofill's down
The below basically checks 2 sheets then checks the month and the score and adds one to the count for every record that matches the criteria onto a 3rd summary sheet, the issue I'm having is when I just have the formula on the excel sheet even with absolute referencing the cell ref moves every time I pull fresh data into the Importdata sheet, so I thought ill get the code to put the cell formula in and that will negate the issue.
Issue being I cant find a way for the formula to increase its month as it fills down, so the criteria Month for B2 is Jan the criteria for B3 is Feb and so on, is there anyone to put this into the formula?
Sub calc()

    Dim lrow As Long
    
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("NPS").Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(ImportData!R[-13]C:R[85]C,""Jan"",ImportData!R[-13]C[22]:R[85]C[22],"">6"",ImportData!R[-13]C[22]:R[85]C[22],""<9"")+COUNTIFS(HistoricalData!R[-13]C:R[85]C,""Jan"",HistoricalData!R[-13]C[22]:R[85]C[22],"">6"",HistoricalData!R[-13]C[22]:R[85]C[22],""<9"")"
        
    Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & lrow)

End Sub

or is it easier to find out why the fresh import of data is casing the absolute cell reference to move?
trying to understand the logic behind incremental increases within a formula

On row 2, TEXT(DATE(2024,ROW()-1,1),"mmm") will return "Jan", on row 3 "Feb" etc.

Or =TEXT(ROW()-1&-1,"mmm")
